# Object not defined

Tags: vba

"channel", "facebook", "instagram" and "twitter" are "Object" data types

"i", "j" and "k" are "integer" data types

"ws" is "Woksheet" data type

```
Set channel = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With channel

    .Add "facebook", facebook
    .Add "instagram", instagram
    .Add "twitter", twitter

End With

Set facebook = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With facebook

    .Add "brand", 0
    .Add "post", 0
    .Add "likes", 0
    .Add "comments", 0
    .Add "boosted", 0
    .Add "shares", 0

End With

Set instagram = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With instagram

    .Add "brand", 0
    .Add "post", 0
    .Add "likes", 0
    .Add "comments", 0

End With

Set twitter = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With twitter

    .Add "brand", 0
    .Add "post", 0
    .Add "likes", 0
    .Add "retweets", 0
    .Add "is retweet", 0

End With

For Each ws In Sheets

    For i = 0 To channel.count - 1

        If channel.Keys()(i) = ws.name Then

            Sheets(ws.name).Activate
            emptyCol = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("1:1"))
            emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))

            For j = 1 To emptyCol

                For k = 0 To channel(channel.Keys()(i)).count - 1

                    If InStr(Cells(1, j), channel(channel.Keys()(i)).Keys()(k)) <> 0 Then

                        channel(channel.Keys()(i))(channel(channel.Keys()(i))) = j
                        MsgBox channel(channel.Keys()(i)) & "." & channel(channel.Keys()(i)) & "=" & j

                    End If

                Next k

            Next j

        End If

    Next i

Next ws
```

The error which is coming up is:[image]

It is highlighting the following code: `For k = 0 To channel(channel.Keys()(i)).count - 1`

Comment: Hi, are you trying to iterate over the dictionary's keys?

Comment: Hi, Yes. Iterating, checking them with the column headers and storing the column number as their item.

Comment: Since you only have 3 items in the dictionary, it might be easier to just use an Array. See this answer for an example to iterate the keys of a dictionary. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39271503/type-mismatch-error-array-parsing-json-array-of-strings-in-vba

Comment: You are saying to use an array instead of the "channel" dictionary?

Comment: Yeah, I mean dictionary are typically employed for fast lookups when you have a lot of items. You have 3 items. You can do it this way, however an Array or even a Collection might be a better fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assembling your `Dictionary` objects in the wrong order.  When this code runs...

```
With channel
    .Add "facebook", facebook
    .Add "instagram", instagram
    .Add "twitter", twitter
End With
```

...`facebook`, `instagram`, and `twitter` aren't set to anything.  I'm guessing they aren't *declared* either, so you're storing empty `Variant`'s instead of objects.  When you eventually create the actual object, it's too late because they were stored in the `Dictionary` *by value*, so the underlying variable just gets changed to point at the new object.  See [Why should I dimension my variables in VBA really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30785133/why-should-i-dimension-my-variables-in-vba-really/30794674#30794674).

The immediate fix is to just reorder the top section of code like this...

```
Set facebook = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
With facebook
    .Add "brand", 0
    .Add "post", 0
    .Add "likes", 0
    .Add "comments", 0
    .Add "boosted", 0
    .Add "shares", 0
End With

Set instagram = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
With instagram
    .Add "brand", 0
    .Add "post", 0
    .Add "likes", 0
    .Add "comments", 0
End With

Set twitter = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
With twitter
    .Add "brand", 0
    .Add "post", 0
    .Add "likes", 0
    .Add "retweets", 0
    .Add "is retweet", 0
End With

Set channel = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
With channel
    .Add "facebook", facebook
    .Add "instagram", instagram
    .Add "twitter", twitter
End With
```

The *solution* is to add Option Explicit which ensures that your variables are properly declared.